# BindingExpression.UpdateSource() throws Specified cast is not valid

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have some code which gets the binding expression of a combobox

```
bindingExpression = ((ComboBox)(((Grid)(control.Content)).Children[0])).GetBindingExpression( ComboBox.SelectedValueProperty );
```

the combobox is defined in xaml

```
<ComboBox Style="{StaticResource UiEditorComboBoxStyle}"
                                  Name="comboBox_Business" 
                                  DisplayMemberPath="Value.Name" 
                                  SelectedValuePath="Value.BusinessId"
                                      >
                                <ComboBox.SelectedValue>
                                    <Binding Path="entity.BusinessId" UpdateSourceTrigger="Explicit" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" ValidatesOnExceptions="True" Mode="TwoWay">
                                        <Binding.ValidationRules>
                                            <validators:ValidationRule_SelectedItem NotSelectedErrorMessage="A Business must be selected"
                                                                                NotSelectedErrorMessageTranslationKey="BusinessMustBeSelected" />
                                        </Binding.ValidationRules>
                                    </Binding>
                                </ComboBox.SelectedValue>
                            </ComboBox>
```

When I call

```
bindingExpression.UpdateSource()
```

I get a 'specified cast is not valid' exception. I'm guessing it' something to do with the type of the property (Guid), but I can't figure out how to deal with it.

The combobox values are bound to a dictionary

any pointers?

cheers,

J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted, I needed to define a custom converter.